# Why does this call with boost::shared_ptr not compile in c++ if I remove the const?

Tags: c++, constants, shared-ptr, temporary

```
#include <boost/smart_ptr.hpp>

class Base {
};

class Derived : public Base {
  public:
    Derived() : Base() {}
};

void func(/*const*/ boost::shared_ptr<Base>& obj) {
}

int main() {
  boost::shared_ptr<Base> b;
  boost::shared_ptr<Derived> d;
  func(b);
  func(d);
}
```

This compiles with the const in func's signature but not without it. The error appears in the line with the call `func(d);`

Any hints for me?

Comment: hint: temporaries can not be bound to non-const references.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When reading the [documentation of `boost::shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) we find the following:

> A `shared_ptr<T>` can be implicitly converted to `shared_ptr<U>` whenever `T*` can be implicitly converted to `U*`.

---

This means that `boost::shared_ptr<Derived>` is implicitly convertable to an object of type `boost::shared_ptr<Base>`.

When this conversion takes place upon executing `func (d)` a temporary will be created, though *non-const* references **cannot** be bound to temporary objects - which is why your compiler issues an error unless you make the argument to `func` a `const&`.

Comment: You could maybe emphasize that shared_ptr<B> and shared_ptr<D> are totally different and unrelated types, and that any conversion that might take places is purely due to defined conversion ctors.. I think the OP misconcept comes from thinking that they are like B* and D*, type relation wise.

Comment: Thank you for your fast and insightful explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `func` had content:

```
void func(boost::shared_ptr<Base>& obj) {
    obj = boost::shared_ptr<Base>(new Base);
}
```

Calling it with `boost::shared_ptr<Derived> d` would be incorrect, as `d` would not contain a pointer to `Derived`.

Comment: That is the reason why shared_ptr works the way it does with the different types, and it is a good thing to know, but it is not the reason why his code fails to compile.